# Will a BlockingQueue look the same to all threads at all times?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, queue

I'm implementing a program where the main thread pushes various messages to worker threads, and worker threads push results of work back to the main thread.

For that I planned to use two queues, one to push to the worker thread, and one to pull from it.

As far as I understand, threads cache objects and thus if they were to `add()` an object to a queue that another thread could `poll()`, this change might not be visible immediately, i.e. it might not be synchronized. Is this correct?

However, if I were to use a `BlockingQueue`, all operations on this queue are supposed to be immediately visible to all threads?

Comment: `BLockngQueue` is in the `Java.util.concurrent` package. That entire package is for concurrent (thread safe) programming. Anything that implements that interface is meant for exactly what you want.

Comment: @BrianRoach which may or may not answer my question... I read the docs for the class but it mentions how it just blocks until another thread is ready to read from it, not that it will cause threads to refresh their cache.

Comment: @yannbane ignoring again, that that whole package is for concurrent programming, safe publishing (thread caching) involves the *reference* to an object in a given class, not necessarily the contents of it. A `BlockingQueue` is entirely threadsafe but its visibility in terms of what you're talking about is dependent on the containing class is publishing it correctly (either through a `final` variable, or `volatile` variable) or simply relying on the happens-before behavior.

Comment: @Flo Just an FYI, that is absolutely incorrect in Java.

Comment: I'm kind of confused now. Could you please see my comment on Peter's answer below? I thought that the entire problem is that I cannot just create an object in one thread, pass it to another thread, and then use that object to communicate between threads - because both threads keep a local cache of this object that is not guaranteed to be refreshed at all (however Peter says that it is refreshed after 50 - 100 nano-seconds).

Comment: If you use a `BlockingQueue`, you can *not* assume that “*all operations* on this queue are supposed to be immediately visible to *all threads*”. Rather, all operations *the one* thread putting an object has performed before that put are visible to *the one* thread taking that very object after the put. So it’s very natural to limit the thread safety expectations to the modifications made to the very object being transferred through the `BlockingQueue` before the initiation of the transfer. If you really want to publish an object to *all threads* `BlockingQueue` is not the right mechanism.

Comment: @Holger, thank you, that cleared a lot up. So, I modify an object, put it in a BlockingQueue, and eventually it gets removed by another thread: that thread is guaranteed to have my modifications. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @yannbane: Yes, that’s the intended use case of `BlockingQueue`. If the receiving thread makes further modifications to the object and sends it back through another `BlockingQueue`, that will work. The important point is to *never* modify an object *after* the put. If the receiver will modify the object, the sender must not even read the object’s state after the put as it would have undefined results. The typical scenarios are producer/consumer like where the sender forgets about the object entirely after the put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you are talking about thread safe data structures or constructs.  If you use regular non-thread safe fields, there is no guarantees it will work, but there is also no guarantees that it won't work.  Note: this is unit testing for thread safe useful, but not fool proof.

> this change might not be visible immediately, i.e. it might not be synchronized. Is this correct?

Yes. The delay is usually in the order of 50 - 100 nano-seconds, so it might be almost immediate.

> all operations on this queue are supposed to be immediately visible to all threads?

That is not possible in a real machine.  What you can say is that you should never get an error due to visibility problems, mostly very slight delays. (However since it creates garbage you can get a Full GC delay in the worst case, if the machine doesn't get hibernated in which case the delay could be hours or days)

Comment: If threads A and B have a reference to the same object, and A changes the object, then this change is guaranteed to eventually be visible in thread B? I thought that threads keep caches of objects for a longer time and that for example if you wanted to share a variable of an object between them and still be guaranteed that the change will be visible to both threads, you had to use the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: Correct, and it is also guaranteed that you won't see an inconsistent update.  This is the more important feature.  The change will be visible to both threads but nothing happens immediately in a CPU.  The minimum clock cycle is ~0.3 ns and if you set a volatile variable and read it in another thread it will take at least 70 clock cycles. If you write to a volatile and read it in the *same* thread it will take about 5 ns. For complex data structures like queue which allocate objects, this takes in the order of 50 - 100 ns.

Comment: All other answers/comments would suggest that *"If threads A and B have a reference to the same object, and A changes the object, then this change is guaranteed to eventually be visible in thread B?"* - is **false**, not correct! E.g. it has nothing to do with that latency you mentioned but with the way *threads in Java* are implemented. I think that you answered the question about threads *in general*...

Comment: @yannbane I don't understand your comment.  Why do you believe the statement is false?  What reference do you have?

Comment: @yannbane Have you read the other answers?  I don't see an inconsistency.

Comment: Look at Holger's comment (last as of now) on the original question, and Brian's answer and the two comments on that answer. As I understand it, threads cache all objects locally and thus the changes they make are not guaranteed to be visible to other threads, *unless* using some thread-safe synchronous method or object (like `BlockingQueue`). For primitives that can be accomplished with the `volatile` keyword that makes sure all threads r/w this value from main memory.

Comment: @yannbane All the examples you gave implied you were using thread safe code, indeed all the implementations of BlockingQueue are thread safe.  If you don't use thread safe code then you don't have guarantees, though there is no guarantee it wouldn't work either. I am confused as what the point of the question is.

Comment: Seems like I forgot what my question was in the meantime, so sorry! :S Could you just edit your answer to include "if you use `BlockingQueue`..."? Then I'll upvote it (can't now because I downvoted it 15mins ago, so it has to be edited)

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for the `BlockingQueue` interface says this:

> "`BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control."

You are therefore guaranteed<sup>1</sup> that changes made to the queue by one thread are visible to other threads "immediately" ... in the sense of the memory model.  Synchronization of `put` and `poll` calls is taken care of.  (Any caching effects are taken care of by the mechanisms mentioned in the javadoc.)

Of course, this does not mean that all of them will see the changes at the semantic level.  That depends on things such as thread scheduling.  (If one object is added to a queue, only one thread will be able to remove it.  If it does this before a second thread gets to see the queue state ... for whatever reason ... the second thread won't notice that an entry was added and then removed.)

The granularity of "immediately" is unspecified as well.  For instance, if the JVM only has use of one CPU / core, then a thread can only return from `poll` after the thread that made the `put` call has been de-scheduled, for whatever reasoned.  In addition, the flushing of changes in the memory caches takes a measurable amount of time.

---

<sup>1 - This assumes that the implementation class fulfils the "contract" ... but if it doesn't it is buggy.</sup>

Comment: "Any caching effects are taken care of by the mechanisms mentioned in the javadoc" - it'd be great if you included some explanations in the answerr

Comment: @yannbane - You want me to explain the Java Memory Model?  No can do! But I can recommend that you buy a copy of "Java Concurrency in Action: by Goetz et al ... and read the last chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original question and the comments, your confusing two different things.

Anything that implements `BlockingQueue` is threadsafe and publishes correctly. The internals of the classes that implement that interface vary, so the claim that "all operations on this queue are supposed to be immediately visible to all threads" may not be true for some definition of *immediate*. "Very quickly" would be a more apt description; it may not be using a blocking/locking mechanism, and there's always thread scheduling involved.

Safe publishing (thread caching) has to do with how threads work in Java, and is a much larger topic. The reference to that `BlockingQueue` has to be safely published for all threads to see it. In most cases when using a structure like that, you're probably doing the right thing. That is, either passing the reference to `Runnable` constructors, or creating it as a `final` variable somewhere. But really, as long as you're not getting a `NullPointerException` ... the threads can see it.

Safe publishing issues come in when you do things like instantiate something inside an object *after* you've passed that object to multiple threads.

The de facto reference on the topic is [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) and is well worth owning.

Comment: OK, that sounds great... However I'm worried that objects that I push in the queue won't be synchronized... I could be wrong.  But if a run method called by thread B creates an object and puts it in the queue that an object that is currently running in thread A has a reference to, will this object be synchronized between the threads? As in it's references? For example `run` creates a `Message` with a single public field called `text`, and sets this field to `"a message"`, and pushes this to the queue (all of that in a synch block), will that object be the same to the other thread?

Comment: Right, that's talking about safe publishing. You're guaranteed that A is going to see everything that happened before it got the reference off the queue. Visibility comes into play once both threads have a reference to the object and you then *modify* that object. Any changes to the object not done via some synchronizing mechanism in B are not guaranteed to be seen in A (and vice versa). For example, if you were to assign a different `String` to `text` in B after A has the reference to the object. Making that field `volatile` for example, would guarantee A saw the change.